# How to run sidekiq in production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a server with apache + passenger.

How will I run `sidekiq` in production? Any configuration needed to run the

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

Thanks

Comment: You should have Redis server running - and that's all.

Comment: I run in console redis-server, it says [14754] 09 Apr 10:07:13 # Opening port: bind: Address already in use.
But if I am sending emails it does not work. No emails are getting

Comment: @MarekLipka..  Running the command 'bundle exec sidekicq' with capistrano .. is working. But If I stop it the emails are not sending.

Answer (score 149):

`bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e production`

`-d`, Daemonize process

`-L`, path to writable logfile

`-C`, path to YAML config file

`-e`, Application environment

Comment: If the sidekiq process crashes for any reason, how will we restart?

Comment: kill `ps aux | grep sidekiq | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
Then, bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e production

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer. See the answer from Brian Warren for the correct way

Answer (score 34):

A better solution than using the daemonization -d flag is to leverage the process supervisor provided by your OS. This is also the [recommendation given by the sidekiq gem's wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#daemonization):

> I strongly recommend people not to use the -d flag but instead use a process supervisor like systemd or upstart to manage Sidekiq (or any other server daemon). This ensures Sidekiq will immediately restart if it crashes for some reason.

The wiki provides a example config files for both upstart and systemd found in the ["examples" directory of the repo](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples).

**NOTE**
On my CentOS 7 server I use rvm (Ruby Version Manger). I had to perform an extra step to ensure that my systemd script (/etc/systemd/system/sidekiq.service) could reliably start and stop sidekiq, even in the case where my ruby and/or gemset paths change in the future. The most important directive is "ExecStart", which looks like the following in my script:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/surveil/bundler exec sidekiq -e production -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

The part of the path "/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/surveil", is actually a symlink, which I recreate with the assistance of ['rvm alias'](https://rvm.io/deployment/init-d) during deployment to ensure that it always points to the app's ruby version and gemset, both of which could feasibly change from one deployment to another. This is achieved by creating a rake task that runs during deployment and does the equivalent of the following:

```
rvm alias delete surveil
rvm alias create surveil ruby-#{new_ruby_version}@#{new_gemset_name}
```

By setting up this alias/symlink during deployment, I can safely leave the systemd script untouched and it will keep working fine. This is because the path "/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/surveil/bundler" always points to the correct version of bundler and thus beneifts from the bundler magic that causes its targets to run in the app's configured ruby/gem environment.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. In sidekiq version > 6.0 daemonisation "-d" flag has been deprecated

Answer (score 19):

You should be able to start Sidekiq as a background process (daemon) by passing the -d argument when you start it up:

`bundle exec sidekiq -d`.

Although this answer should work for you now, please be aware that **if the sidekiq process crashes for any reason the process will have to be manually restarted**. A good starting place  for finding out about more robust ways to run sidekiq in production is here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment