# Deploying sidekiq in server with production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I used `sidekiq` for performing background tasks. It is working great for me. But i am little confused with deploying it in my server. Right now i am starting `sidekiq` manually.

i can use

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d
```

(as daemon)

But author suggest its not recommended strongly. I went through with the [deployment](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment) section of the documentation but lack of expertise in rails made me stuck.

Can anyone explain how to setup `sidekiq` in my server **step by step**?

Comment: Try [sidekiq production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958188/how-to-run-sidekiq-in-production-server)

Comment: i referred that before.There is no step by step they just daemonized the command.I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wrote this last night.  It doesn't cover how to use Capistrano to deploy your Rails app but it does cover the Sidekiq-specific parts:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deploying-to-Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the document.

i didn't understood one line `# change to match your deployment user` ,`setuid deploy`,`setgid deploy`,`env HOME=/home/deploy`. Mean what are they and what should be set in that place?
and how to start `sidekiq` service ?(just this ?`sudo start sidekiq index=0`)

Comment: Start with `initctl start sidekiq`.  `deploy` is the Linux user you are using.